# request body on Server side is an empty array, express node.js REST

Tags: http, rest, post

So I've searched all over for the answer, can't seem to find one

I'm making a nodejs app, and at one point I want to POST data in the form of a JSON to my server. Here is what I have in my 'users.js' on the server:

```
/** Updates the array with the new user information **/
exports.addUser = function(req, res) {
var user = req.body;
var userDB = findByEmail(user.email);
if(userDB == -1){
        //New user - send back user information
            users.push(user);
            res.send(JSON.stringify(user));
```

Whenever I check on Chrome - I see that although I am SENDING the corrent information, the response is just {}

Here's what I have on the client.js

```
var user = {email:userEmail,username:userUsername,password:userPassword};
request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (request)
    {
        request.open("POST","users");
        request.onreadystatechange = function()
        {   
            if (request.readyState == 4 &&
                    request.status == 200){
                    result = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                    if(result == 0)
                    {
                        //Result came back as 0 - Old User, wrong password
                    }
                if(result == 1){
                            //Result came back as 1 - Correct password, old User

                        }

                        if(result.email == userEmail){
                            //Result came back as -1 - New User

                            }
            }
        }

        request.send(JSON.stringify(user));
    }
```

Now everything here I think is correct - because I see the HTTP request coming out good.
However it appears in the 'payload' part of the request - is this normal?

Here is my requires on server.js -

```
var express = require('express');
var questions = require('./Quotes');
var scoreboard = require('./scoreboard');
var users = require('./users');
var app = express();//.createServer();
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));    
    app.use(express.bodyParser());//it will parse json request bodies (as well as others), and place the result in req.body:
});

app.post('/users',users.addUser);
```

Finally here is what the Chrome shows when I test it -

I forgot to add - this is how the request looks on Chrome -

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:70
Content-Type:application/xml
Host:whosaidit.eu01.aws.af.cm
Origin:http://whosaidit.eu01.aws.af.cm
Referer:http://whosaidit.eu01.aws.af.cm/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36
Request Payloadview source
{email:oreporan@gmail.com, username:orepor, password:yotamp}
email: "john@gmail.com"
password: "password"
username: "john123"
```

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things I'm noticing:

- Even though you are encoding your client side data to JSON, you're not telling the server that it's JSON that you are sending to it. Before you send your request, set the content-type:

```
   request.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
   request.send(...);
```

- How is `findByEmail()` implemented? If it queries a database, the chances are that it's implemented asynchronously, meaning that you cannot expect it to return a useful return code.
- This piece of code is confusing:

```
   if (userDB == -1) {
     users.push(user);               // what is 'users'? what's the use of this code?
     res.send(JSON.stringify(user)); // you send back an object, but in your
                                     // client side code you are expecting a
                                     // number: "if (result == 0)"
   }
```

Comment: It's because I've been playing around with it, I will return a number, but for now I just wanted to see what "user" was so I sent it. As of now I don't have a DB. as a matter of fact, even if I just do users = req.body and then res.send(JSON.stringify(user)), its still an empty array

Comment: @user1843115 did you try with the `setRequestHeader`? That at least should solve the problem of receiving the data on the server side.

Comment: Solved!
The problem was indeed as was stated above me. I was missing:

    request.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');